# solve $x(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}+yy\prime(x^2+2y^2)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Help with this excercise.. :)

## $$x(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}+yy\prime(x^2+2y^2)=0$$

the book says it is an exact differential equation, but how?

---

$$x(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}+yy\prime(x^2+2y^2)=0$$
$$x(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}dx+y(x^2+2y^2)dy=0$$

$M=x(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}$

$N=y(x^2+2y^2)$

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=-\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=2xy$$

I cant find the integrating factor,, :(

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not an exact differential equation.  Moreover, I don't think it has closed-form solutions at all: Maple doesn't find any.  Are you sure you don't have a typo?

Comment: no, 
I checked,, mm,, I will ask my teacher

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $x(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}+yy\prime(x^2+2y^2)=0$ isn't an exact differential equation.

So, there is a typo. Moreover the equation is certainly simple. The simplest guess is :
$$x(x^2+y^2)+yy\prime(x^2+2y^2)=0$$
$$x(x^2+y^2)dx+y(x^2+2y^2)dy=0$$
If it is the exact differential of $F(x,y)$ then :

$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=x(x^2+y^2) \quad\to\quad F=\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+f(y)\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=y(x^2+2y^2) \quad\to\quad F=\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+2\frac{y^4}{4}+g(x)
\end{cases}$

which implies $f(y)=\frac{y^4}{2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{x^4}{4}$

$F=\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{2}=\text{constant}\quad$ because $dF=0$

$$x^4+2x^2y^2+2y^4=c$$
Solving it for $y$ leads to :
$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-x^2\pm \sqrt{2c-x^4}}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$x(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}+yy'(x^2+2y^2)=0$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}(x^2+2y^2)=-\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\dfrac{y(x^2+2y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}$

Let $t=y^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{dx}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dy}=2y\dfrac{dx}{dt}$

$\therefore2y\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{y(x^2+2y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{(x^2+2y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2x}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{(x^2+2t)\sqrt{x^2+t}}{2x}$

Let $u=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dt}=2x\dfrac{dx}{dt}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{2x}\dfrac{du}{dt}=-\dfrac{(x^2+2t)\sqrt{x^2+t}}{2x}$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=-(x^2+2t)\sqrt{x^2+t}$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=-(u+2t)\sqrt{u+t}$

Let $v=-\sqrt{u+t}$ ,

Then $u=v^2-t$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=2v\dfrac{dv}{dt}-1$

$\therefore2v\dfrac{dv}{dt}-1=(v^2+t)v$

$2v\dfrac{dv}{dt}=v^3+tv+1$

$(vt+v^3+1)\dfrac{dt}{dv}=2v$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.